# Doctrine 2: Joining two tables ManyToOne

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm having some issues when trying to join two tables with Doctrine 2.  When I attempt to add a new item to the table I get the error:

A new entity was found through a relationship that was not configured to cascade persist operations: @. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship.

When I try to update a row in the table I'm getting the error:

The given entity has no identity.

I'm trying to join the winner entities event id to the id of an event so i can gather data on the event for the view.  I'm defiantly getting an id returned for from the form for the update but it doesn't seem to let me update it.

**Update:**
So having played around with things a little, when I add the cascade="{persist}" option I get a class not found error, removing it and adding the full namespace results in it claiming the entity does not exist...

```php
<?php

namespace ZC\Entity;

/**
 * ZC\Entity\Winner
 *
 * @Table(name="winner")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="ZC\Entity\Repository\Winner")
 */

class Winner
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=false, precision=0, scale=0)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $copy
     *
     * @Column(name="copy", type="text", length="", unique=false, nullable=true, precision=0, scale=0)
     */
    protected $copy;

    /**
     * @var string $url
     *
     * @Column(name="url", type="string", length="255", unique=false, nullable=true, precision=0, scale=0)
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Events")
     * @JoinColumns=({
     *  @JoinColumn(name="event", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     *
     */
    protected $event;


    /**
     * __get function.
     * 
     * @access protected
     * @param mixed $property
     * @return void
     */
    public function __get($property) {
        return $this->$property;
    }

    /**
     * __set function.
     * 
     * @access protected
     * @param mixed $property
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    } 

}



<?php

namespace ZC\Entity;

/**
 * ZC\Entity\Events
 *
 * @Table(name="events")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="ZC\Entity\Repository\Events")
 */

class Events
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=false, precision=0, scale=0)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @Column(name="title", type="string", length="255", unique=false, nullable=false, precision=0, scale=0)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     *
     * @Column(name="description", type="text", length="", unique=false, nullable=true, precision=0, scale=0)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var string $status
     *
     * @Column(name="status", type="smallint", length="1", unique=false, nullable=false, precision=0, scale=0)
     */
    protected $status = 0;

    /**
     * @var string $date
     *
     * @Column(name="date", type="string", length="255", unique=false, nullable=false, precision=0, scale=0)
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @var string $lang
     *
     * @Column(name="lang", type="string", length="255", unique=false, nullable=false, precision=0, scale=0)
     */
    protected $lang;


    /**
     * __get function.
     * 
     * @access protected
     * @param mixed $property
     * @return void
     */
    public function __get($property) {
        return $this->$property;
    }

    /**
     * __set function.
     * 
     * @access protected
     * @param mixed $property
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cascade={"persist"}`:

```
/**
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Entity\Events", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumns=({
 *  @JoinColumn(name="event", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 *
 */
protected $event;
```

Comment: I now get an error when trying to create a new event stating: Class does not exist

Comment: Try including the namespace. I updated my answer. If that won't work, could you post your event entity code

Comment: adding cascade={"persist"} results in my getting a Class does not exist error, adding the namespace results in my getting a Not a valid entity or mapped super class error

Comment: This worked fine without the namespaces, I just had an error in my model when setting the shared data, and similarly in my controller populating the field